# TFTP Server With Red Hat 7

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, systemd, tftp, firewalld

How do I set up a TFTP Server w/ Red Hat 7?  This is a fresh VM install of RHEL 7.3. I'm using the RHEL 7 Installation Guide instructions at  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/pdf/Installation_Guide/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7-Installation_Guide-en-US.pdf which basically amount to the following:

```
# yum install tftp-server
# firewall-cmd --add-service=tftp 
# firewall-cmd --add-service=tftp --permanent
# systemctl start tftp
# systemctl enable tftp
```

Having done that, netstat still shows no listening on udp/69 and I get "Connection request failed" from the Windows 10 host machine that the RHEL VM is running on.  They can ping each other fine and nmap from the host machine shows:

```
69/udp open|filtered tftp
```

Ps on the Red Hat 7 VM shows:

```
root       4269      1  0 21:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/in.tftpd -s /var/lib/tftpboot
```

Everything seems right to me except no listening port in netstat and of course I can't *actually* connect.  Has anyone got it to work successfully?